# jqGrid, edit mode, serialize multi select

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

When editing column with `edittype: select` and `multiple: true`, jqGrid sends the data to the server as comma-separated values. Is that possible to bind some event to this specific column, which will return an array instead of comma-separated values?

I'd like to **avoid** using **serializeEditData** event, since

1. this one is grid-specific, not column-specific which would be a trouble for me - I'm trying to separate column logic from grid logic
2. it does not sound like a good idea to convert array to string, and the string to the very same array again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you will have to use `edittype: 'custom'` in the case and provide your custom implementations of `custom_element` and `custom_value` methods of `editoptions`. If the value from the custom input element will be need to read jqGrid will call `custom_value` method with the parameter `'get'` parameter. Your implementation of `custom_value` method could return array of items in the case.

It's important to understand that in general you will need to implement custom formatter which allows to display array of data which are input for multiselect. Fortunately `formatter: "select"` has [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L349)

```
cellval = cellval + "";
```

which convert array to comma separated items. Because of the line the array will by converted to string by usage of `.join(",")` and `formatter: "select"` successfully accepts arrays as input.

[The demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectWithMultiselectCustom.htm)

[image]

demonstrates the described above approach. It uses the following code:

```
{
    name: "Subcategory",
    width: 250,
    formatter: "select",
    edittype: "custom",
    editoptions: {
        value: {"1": "football", "2": "formula 1", "3": "physics", "4": "mathematics"},
        custom_element: function (value, options) {
            return $.jgrid.createEl.call(this, "select",
                $.extend(true, {}, options, {custom_element: null, custom_value: null}),
                value);
        },
        custom_value: function ($elem, operation, value) {
            if (operation === "get") {
                return $elem.val();
            }
        },
        multiple: true
    }
}
```

In the above code I use `$.jgrid.createEl` to create multivalue select by existing code of jqGrid. The only thing which one need to do is removing of `custom_element` and `custom_value` from the options to prevent unneeded call of the methods from [setAttributes](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.common.js#L282). If one would modify [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.common.js#L283) of `setAttributes` code and include `"custom_value"` and `"custom_element"` in the list of excluded attributes the expression `$.extend(true, {}, options, {custom_element: null, custom_value: null})` could be reduced to `options`.

In the way we get almost the same `<select>` as using `edittype: "select"`. There are two differences only:

- the `<select>` element created inside of `edittype: "custom"` will have additional attribute `class="customelement"`
- the `<select>` element created inside of `edittype: "custom"` will be wrapped (will be direct child) inside of `<span class="editable">...</span>`

Such differences seems be not important in our case.

**UPDATED**: The code of `setAttributes` method is now fixed in the main code of jqGrid on the gtihub (see [the suggestion](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/413#issuecomment-12469810) and [the commit](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/59c3ccb8b5d627418dcaae10a97388f97c250350)). So in the next version of jqGrid (higher as 4.4.1) one could reduce the code of `custom_element` to

```
custom_element: function (value, options) {
    return $.jgrid.createEl.call(this, "select", options, value);
}
```

See [the corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectWithMultiselectCustom1.htm).

Comment: I was expecting your answer here Oleg! Thank you!

Comment: @migajek: You are welcome! I don't tested m suggestion in case of remote saving of data, but I think it works exactly in the same way.

Comment: @migajek: I wrote small "**UPDATED**" part to my answer.