# jqgrid Custom formatter while editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In jQgrid, while editing i want my custom controls. for eg textbox with custom attributes. to achive this i added customformatter like below

**ColModel**

```
{ name: 'Code', index: 'Code', width: 100, editable: true, formatter : createexceltextbox },
```

**Formatter method**

```
 function createexceltextbox(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return "<input type='text' value='" + cellvalue + "' style='width:100%' abc='xyz'  />";
    }
```

It converts all cells into textbox which i dont want,

I want this textbox at the time of row editing only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) are used during filling the cell content and not during editing. What you need is the usage of [edittype: "custom"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom). [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3055626/315935), [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4842450/315935) (or more recent [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10284605/315935)) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14408189/315935) will provide you corresponding examples.