# Different custom formatters for inline and form editing

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to show a different custom formatter for cell and form editing? Currently I'm using a custom formatter for the cell, which is defined in the ColModel as following

```
formatter:functionName
```

But it does not work on the edit form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are misunderstanding when custom formatter will be used. It will be used for filling the grid body and not during any editing (cell, inline or form editing). It can be that you need to implement [custom editing control](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom) (`edittype: "custom"` and `editoptions` with `custom_element` and `custom_value` callback functions}). You should describe more exactly what you need to implement.

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14408189/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744780/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15694509/315935) for more examples about implementing of custom editing controls.

Comment: thanks! just a small correction: "edittype" instead of "editable"

Comment: @volocuga: You are welcome! Thanks you too for pointing on my typing error.